# Explain the grammar function of the word in the sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Here is next sentence:

> I have lain awake under the skins.

I understand the meaning but the sentence structure makes me confuse. I can't actually understand why the word "awake" stands here like that. If I wrote a sentence, I'd write it like this:

> I have lain and awoken under the skins.

Would you explain to me what "awake" doing here in its form?

Comment: What are the skins?

Comment: Have you looked up _awake_ in a dictionary? Why do you think “and awoken” (a verb phrase) would fit better than “awake” (an adjective)?

Answer (score 1):

Why say **lain awake** rather than **lain and awoken**?

You would not say **awoken** if you had never gone to sleep in the first place. For instance, if you had been lying there for an hour, unsuccessfully trying to *get* to sleep . . .

Also, **lain and awoken** uses two separate verbs. But **lain** ***awake*** is a a single verb followed by an adverb; it describes *how* you were lying. So, syntactically, the two sentences are essentially different.